# Where's the equivalent of Dual for Applicative?

Tags: haskell

[`Dual`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Dual) is a newtype-wrapper that just reverses the order of `mappend` for the wrapped type's `Monoid` instance:

```
>>> "hello" <> " " <> "world"
"hello world"
>>> getDual $ Dual "hello" <> Dual " " <> Dual "world"
"world hello"
```

Equivalently, one could define a newtype-wrapper `Swap` that reverses the order of `<*>` for the wrapped type's `Applicative` instance:

```
newtype Swap f a = Swap { getSwap :: f a } deriving Functor
instance Applicative f => Applicative (Swap f) where
  pure = Swap . pure
  Swap mf <*> Swap ma = Swap $ (\a f -> f a) <$> ma <*> mf

>>> ("hello", replicate) <*> (" ", 5) <*> ("world", ())
("hello world", [(),(),(),(),()])
>>> getSwap $ Swap ("hello", replicate) <*> Swap (" ",5) <*> Swap ("world", ())
("world hello", [(),(),(),(),()])
```

I could have sworn there was an equivalent to `Swap` in `base`, but I can't seem to find it. Is there an commonly-used equivalent in some other package?

Comment: There is also `<**> ::  Applicative f => f a -> f (a -> b) -> f b` if that helps

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are looking for `Backwards`, from [*transformers*' `Control.Applicative.Backwards`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.5.0/docs/Control-Applicative-Backwards.html):

```
-- | The same functor, but with an 'Applicative' instance that performs
-- actions in the reverse order.
newtype Backwards f a = Backwards { forwards :: f a }

-- etc.

-- | Apply @f@-actions in the reverse order.
instance (Applicative f) => Applicative (Backwards f) where
    pure a = Backwards (pure a)
    {-# INLINE pure #-}
    Backwards f <*> Backwards a = Backwards (a <**> f)
    {-# INLINE (<*>) #-}
```

[`(<**>)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--42--42--62-), from `Control.Applicative`, is, as you'd expect:

```
-- | A variant of '<*>' with the arguments reversed.
(<**>) :: Applicative f => f a -> f (a -> b) -> f b
(<**>) = liftA2 (\a f -> f a)
```